# What is the best performing way (fast loading time) to create a big (GIS) data map with with ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, user-interface, gis, bigdata

We are looking to development an application which gives our users insight into properties of their real estate compared to other real estate in The Netherlands. We want to present this information graphically on a map (with something like Google map or OpenStreetMap).

We want to use big data from our countries GIS data system to get coloured footprints of all the buildings in The Netheralnds on the map. 
The colour of the footprints will resemble a certain type of information like energy consumption.

This will look something like [energielabelatlas.nl](http://energielabelatlas.nl) or [maps.amsterdam.nl/energie_gaselektra/](http://maps.amsterdam.nl/energie_gaselektra/) (more examples on [maps.amsterdam.nl](http://maps.amsterdam.nl/)).

The problem we now face is to how we can get the fastest loading time if we want the user to be able to select out of multiple options which type of data is displayed (energy consumption, materials used, type of building and more).

As I see it we have two options:

1. Dynamically draw polygon surfaces on the map
2. Create several maps (generate the tiles with [TileMill](http://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/)) as explained by Bert Spaan in [this GitHub project](https://github.com/bertspaan/buildings)

Problem with option 1 is loading speed/reaction time from the application as can be seen with [the energy example](http://maps.amsterdam.nl/energie_gaselektra/).

Problem with option 2 is that we want to have multiple options a user can choose from and/or filter the data that is shown on the map. This means we have to generate a lot of maps.

So my questions are:

- Are these the only options we have?
- We want to develop the application in ASP.NET MVC, perhaps the .NET framework offers some options?
- Which of the above options do you think is best to achieve our goals?

Comment: **primarily opinion-based** _Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise._

Comment: **too broad** _There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs._

Comment: The best option - don't display a big map, only display what can be reasonably shown on screen. That's what Google Maps does. Don't try to recreate a map viewer, either use Google Maps itself or find an existing library, as these already handle dynamic loading, drawing (with or without vector graphics), layering, zooming etc.

Answer (score 1):

Quick dump of ideas before the question gets closed.

The best option is - don't display a big map, only display what can be reasonably shown on screen. That's what Google or Bing Maps do. By the way, both are available as services to allow you to build your own application. This is probably the best option as they handle the real dirty work of managing the maps, updates, polygons etc.

Don't try to recreate a map viewer, either use Google Maps itself or find an existing library. These already handle concerns like:

- Dynamic loading of the visible view
- Drawing using SVG or falling back to other methods
- Defining and rendering layers
- Zooming in/out and limiting what is visible based on the zoom level.

ASP.NET MVC or better yet, Web API can provide the backend code, especially the REST services that provide the data to display.